# How to create a selectable list where the list items are bound to buttons with an event using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I came across a problem with JQuery.

I would like to create a list where the items are selected by clicking on a button in a set of buttons. Basically I have 3 buttons with a grey background color, each with its own id="" attribute and an unordered list of 3 list items with initial display set to "none" (they are also with their own id).

I'm aiming to achieve this result:

1) When I click on one of the 3 buttons, the one I have clicked on becomes active with a green background-color (I toggle a class called buttonListActive for that, ***using the .toggleClass() method***) and the corresponding list item comes out with an animation (I use the ***.animate() method*** for this);

2) If I click on the same button (which now is active), the list item that came out before disappears again with an animation and the button becomes grey (which means no more active) again;

3) If I click on a button while another button is active, the list item of the active button disappears an it becomes grey (so it is no more active), and the new button I have clicked on becomes active and its list item comes out with an animation;

4) If I click inside of the displayed list item or inside the ul element ( with a blue background) nothing should happen;

5) If I click outside of the ul element (which contains the displayed list item), The list item should disappear and its active button should become gray again (no more active);

I am sorry if I am repeating myself, but I want to be as clear as possible in order to make you understand this need.

Here is my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"/>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Lists</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        // button1 -> item1
        $(function() {
                $("#button1").click(function(e){
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        if ($("#item1").css("display") == "block") {
                                $("#item1").animate({ width: "0" }, 300, function() {
                                        $("#item1").css({ "display": "none"});
                                        $("#button1").toggleClass("buttonListActive");
                                });
                                return;
                        }

                        $(this).toggleClass("buttonListActive");
                        $("#item1").css("display", "block");
                        $("#item1").animate({ width: "500px"}, 300 );
                });

                // button2 -> item2
                $("#button2").click(function(e){
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        if ($("#item2").css("display") == "block") {
                                $("#item2").animate({ width: "0" }, 300, function() {
                                        $("#item2").css({ "display": "none"});
                                        $("#button2").toggleClass("buttonListActive");
                                });
                                return;
                        }

                        $(this).toggleClass("buttonListActive");
                        $("#item2").css("display", "block");
                        $("#item2").animate({ width: "500px"}, 300 );
                });

                // button3 -> item3
                $("#button3").click(function(e){
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        if ($("#item3").css("display") == "block") {
                                $("#item3").animate({ width: "0" }, 300, function() {
                                        $("#item3").css({ "display": "none"});
                                        $("#button3").toggleClass("buttonListActive");
                                });
                                return;
                        }

                        $(this).toggleClass("buttonListActive");
                        $("#item3").css("display", "block");
                        $("#item3").animate({ width: "500px"}, 300 );
                });

        });

        $(document).click(function(e){
                console.log($(e.target));
                    if ($.contains(document.getElementById("ListID"), e.target) || $(e.target).is("#ListID")) { return; }

                    $("#item1").animate({ width: "0" }, 300, function() {
                                        $("#item1").css({ "display": "none"});
                                        $(".buttonListActive").toggleClass("buttonListActive");
                                });

                    $("#item2").animate({ width: "0" }, 300, function() {
                                        $("#item2").css({ "display": "none"});

                                });

                    $("#item3").animate({ width: "0" }, 300, function() {
                                        $("#item3").css({ "display": "none"});

                                });

        });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
            font-family:Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
            color:white;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    }

    button {
            color:inherit;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 10px;
    }

    .buttonListActive {
            background:#44D574;
    }

    ul li {
            font-family:inherit;
            display:none;
            width:200px;
            height:20px;
    }

    #ListID {
            padding:10px;
            background:#006ED6;
            height:100px;
            width:800px;
    }

    ul li.listItem {
            background:#D61F2C;
            margin-top:10px;
    }
</style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="buttons">
  <button id="button1" class="buttonList" name="button">Click to see list item1</button>
  <button id="button2" class="buttonList" name="button">Click to see list item2</button>
  <button id="button3" class="buttonList" name="button">Click to see list item3</button>
  </div>
  <ul id="ListID">
  <li id="item1" class="listItem">This is some button1 text</li>
  <li id="item2" class="listItem">This is some button2 text</li>
  <li id="item3" class="listItem">This is some button3 text</li>
     </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

Actually I can achieve the point 1, 2, 4 and 5, but I can't get how to switch from a button to another and make the needed changes with the list items.

Also, I would like to know if there's a smarter way implementing the event handlers instead like I did in my JQuery code, cause it looks so anti-DRY.

Thanks for the attention! Waiting for an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight change in your HTML `data` attribute:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button id="button1" class="buttonList" name="button" data-target="item1">Click to see list item1</button>
    <button id="button2" class="buttonList" name="button" data-target="item2">Click to see list item2</button>
    <button id="button3" class="buttonList" name="button" data-target="item3">Click to see list item3</button>
</div>
<ul id="ListID">
    <li id="item1" class="listItem">This is some button1 text</li>
    <li id="item2" class="listItem">This is some button2 text</li>
    <li id="item3" class="listItem">This is some button3 text</li>
</ul>
```

And simple script for every button:

```
$(function () {
    $('.buttonList').on('click', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();

        var target = $('#' + $(this).data('target'));
        if(target.css('display') == 'block') {

            target.animate({
                width: 0
            }, 500, function(){
                target.hide();
            });
            $(this).toggleClass('buttonListActive');
            return;
        } else {
            $('.listItem').hide().width(0);
            $('.buttonList').attr('class', 'buttonList');
        }
        $(this).toggleClass('buttonListActive');
        target.show().animate({width: "500px"}, 500);
    });
});
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8c66j/1/)

Update to [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8c66j/3/)

Comment: Thank you, but then when I click on another button I would like to get an effect like this: at the same time the actual list item with display:block disappears with the width animation and the new list item that must be shown comes out with animation. How can I achieve that??

Comment: It's getting closer, I would like them disappear and appear simultaneously (i.e. the disappearing and appearing animation of the respective list items should happen at the same time).
Is it possible? I guess it is, but do not know how...